# Functors in C++ to prevent duplication?

Tags: c++, c++11

**Important Note: I am coding according to C++11 standard**

I have to write the following operators for my `IntMatrix` class (which check if every element in the matrix is `<,>,==,!=,etc...` the given parameter):

```
    IntMatrix operator< (int num) const;
    IntMatrix operator> (int num) const;
    IntMatrix operator>= (int num) const;
    IntMatrix operator<= (int num) const;
    IntMatrix operator== (int num) const;
    IntMatrix operator!= (int num) const;
```

So, to prevent code duplications and since the implementation is nearly the same I thought about writing one functor called `between(int from, int to)` which checks if number is in a given field.

**For example:**

for `operator>` I would use between(num+1,LargestPossibleint)

for `operator<:` between(SmallestPossibleInt,num-1)

for `operator==:` between(num,num)

for `operator!=:` between(num+1,num-1)

But as you can see my code depends of values like LargestPossibleint and SmallestPossibleInt which I don't want, (And don't believe this is a good solution)
May someone suggest an edit for this (Maybe default value for parameters may help)?

**Update: I can't use lambda, macros or anything not in standard level**
What I learnt?
All basic stuff in C++, classes, functors, operation overloading, templates, generic code...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: As an aside, this is a common complaint. So much so that they standardized a new operator, <=> to reduce all the boilerplate. Soon we'll have metaclasses that can help too

Comment: If using C++20, look up the "spaceship operator" for a starting point.

Comment: @dfri no, my question is completely different

Comment: @Peter I am using C++11

Comment: In what way is the dependence on largest possible int or smallest possible int an issue? There is a facility called "std::numeric_limits" with functions for this, so you don't have to worry about those values being different for different compilation targets.

Also, depending on how often those matrices are manipulated compared to how often those expressions comparisons are made, you may just want to store a int max and int min and update them when the numbers in the matrix are changed. That could simplify (and speed up) the implementation of those operators.

Comment: so maybe you should provide `all_elements_between` but not provide the operators? The way you define them is not intuitive

Comment: @Ikaros I like the solution of int max and int min, But isn't storing values to be used only by one functions "not smart"?

Comment: @clark_smith  That depends. If you build one large matrix and compare it to many numbers, then you are implicitly calculating min and max over and over, walking over all values every time, which is certainly not smart either. The cost of storing those values is the size of two ints, i.e. O(1), while the matrix might be much larger anyways. On the other hand, if you almost never call those comparisons, then updating min and max each time you change a value in the matrix might be bad, so it really depends on how that matrix is used.

Answer (score 3):

You could use templates and write the following function:

```
template<class Comp>
bool cmp_with(int num, Comp cmp) const {
    for(size_t i =0 ; i < width; ++i) {
         for(size_t j = 0; j< height; j++) {
             if(!cmp(matrix[i][j], num)) { 
                 return false;
             }
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Of course, you have to adapt this with your element access etc.
Then use it like this:

```
bool operator<(int num) const {
    return cmp_with(num, std::less<int>{});
}
```

and so on. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) for the different function objects (like `std::less`) you need.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use this

Comment: @clark_smith What specifically in this are you not allowed to use?

Comment: The update does not exclude anything used in my answer.

Comment: @Ikaros - the constraints on the question suggest this is a homework exercise.   It's fairly common for homework exercises to require implementing things without using anything from the standard library other than I/O, without using macros (although I wouldn't use them anyway in C++), .....

Answer (score 1):

No lambda? Macrology!

```
#define ALLOF(op) \
bool operator op (int num) const { \
    for (auto& v : data) if (!(v op num)) return false; \
    return true; \
}
ALLOF(<)
ALLOF(<=)
ALLOF(>)
ALLOF(>=)
ALLOF(==)
ALLOF(!=)
#undef ALLOF
```

Comment: Sorry! forgot to mention my professor believes that define and macros are always bad solutions...

Comment: @clark_smith: Most of the times they're bad indeed... but always question someone that uses the word "always" in IT ;-)

Comment: @6502 This is just horrible. I love it ;-)